# How to post values of buttons which are turned on?

Tags: php, jquery

I need help on being able to post the correct buttons into the database. But I don't know what to call the $_POST method when posting the values of the button.

I have an application which you can view [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php)

Please follow steps below in order to use application:

1. Click on the "Open Grid" link and select button "5", you will see 5 buttons "A-E" appear below.
2. Click on button 'A' and 'C', these buttons would turn green meaning that they have been turned on.
3. Now click on the "Add question" button to append what you have done into a table row below.
4. Now please repeat steps 1-3 again but this time choose button "7" so you will see buttons "A-G" and click on buttons 'B', 'D' and 'F' so that these buttons are turned on.

Now you will see that there are 2 table rows, first table row has buttons 'A' and 'C' turned on and second row has buttons 'B', 'D' and 'F' turned on.

What my question is that how do I $_POST only those turned on buttons only (In example above it should post 'A' and 'C', and it should post 'B', 'D' and 'F'? What is the $_POST method I need to write?

Below is the code where it outputs the letter buttons in the top control and in the appended rows:

Letter buttons in top control

```
<table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
<tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        Option and Answer
    </th>
</tr>
        <?php
            $a = range("A","Z");
        ?>

        <table id="answerSection">
            <tr>

        <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach($a as $key => $val){
                if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
                echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
                if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
                $i++;
            }
        ?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>
        <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerTrueName"  id="answerTrue"  type="button"   value="True"    onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
        <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerFalseName" id="answerFalse"     type="button"   value="False"   onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
        <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerYesName"   id="answerYes"   type="button"   value="Yes"     onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
        <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerNoName"    id="answerNo"        type="button"   value="No"      onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is letter buttons appended into each row

```
    function insertQuestion(form) {   

                var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');
        var currenttotal = context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length;        



        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
        var $td = $("<td class='extratd'>");
        var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>3. Answer:<br/></div>");


    var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
    $('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if(i%7 == 0) {
            $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
            $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
        }
        var $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />".replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id')+'Row');

        $newBtn.appendTo($cell);

        i++;
    });


        $tr.append($td);
        $td.append($answer);
        $tbody.append($tr); 


    }
```

Below is the jquery function where it turns on and off the buttons:

```
function btnclick(btn)
{
    var context = $(btn).parents('#optionAndAnswer');
    if (context.length == 0) {
        context = $(btn).parents('tr');
    }
    var $btn = $(btn);

$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff");
$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn");

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using hidden input fields each time you press a button? And when you de-press it, you can remove the input field - all this via Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: @AeroCross Can you quickly provide me a sample code on how you could do it by the hidden input method. IT will be greatly appreciated and then I will be able to see how this can be achieved. Thats a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow-up to my comment, you could try something like this:

Each time you press an "answer" (one of those numeric values), you can add a hidden input to your form containing the value and an unique identifier:

```
$('.answerBtns').on('click', function() {
    // when clicking an answer button, get the value, and id, since you'll need them
    var btn     = $(this);
    var value   = btn.val();
    var id      = btn.attr('id');

    // is the button pressed and turned on?
    if ($(this).hasClass('answerBtnsOff')) {
        // append those values to the form
        var input = '<input type="hidden" value="' + value + '" name="' + id + 'value" />';
        $('#QandA').append(input);

        // toggle the button
        btn.removeClass('answerBtnsOff').addClass('answerBtnsOn');

    // do the opposite - remove the input
    } else {
        $('#QandA').remove('#' + id + 'value');
        btn.removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }

});
```

However, you would need to have some way to identify that those answers belong to a specific question. You woul, for instance, use a counter for each sent question and append it to the name of the fields, so it ends up being something like `answerBid1` for the first question, etc.

Comment: Hi, I got an idea on how to match each answer to a specific question. Do I need to include all of the $_POST for each answer though in the next php page e.g. `$_POST['answerAvalue'], $_POST['answerBvalue'], $_POST['answerCvalue']` etc?

Comment: Yup, you can do that, it's the easier way. You could also put them in the `$_SESSION` array (via `session_start()`) after you POST them, if you need several page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) attribute to fields when you turn them off.

Comment: I want to post the data after the user clicks on the "Submit" button when they submit the form, is it possible that when the user submits the form, it disables the off buttons so then it posts only the on buttons? I don't want to disable the buttons when I append the row because the user can change there mind and turn on a button within a row if they wish. Do you know what the $_POST method should then be written as when I post the values of the turned on buttons?

Comment: The idea was that you'd remove the `disabled` attribute when a user turns a button on. If you want to do it on post you could do something like: `$(function(){ $('form').submit(function() { $('.answerBtnsOff').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); return true; }); });`

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean, sorry. But what my question is that if I want to post the values of the turned on button (non-disabled) buttons onto the next page, then what should $_POST['....'] be? because each button has its own unique name. Unless I have to $_POST each button indivdually E.g. `$_POST['AnswerAName']; $_POST['AnswerBName'];, $_POST['AnswerCName'];` etc

Comment: If I want to toggle between disabling and undisabling buttons, can you show me how to insert this in my btnclick() function. Is it like so: `$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff").removeAttr("disabled");
$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn").attr("disabled", "disabled");` I just want to make sure that if a button if off (disabled), that I am able to turn that button on again